# How to resolve Misaligned Entity Annotation error in RASA NLU

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spacy, rasa-nlu

I am trying to import a LUIS schema model into RASA and trying to train it using the spacy + scikit pipeline. I am using RASA NLU v0.10.4

But when I try to load the LUIS model schema the ner_crf component is throwing a **Misaligned Entity Annotation** warning.

[image: Misaligned Entity Annotation]

Although I have tagged the entities correctly in the LUIS model schema.

Here is my config file:

```
{
    "project": "SynonymsExample",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\RASA\\models",
    "response_log": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\RASA\\logs",
    "pipeline": "spacy_sklearn", 
    "data": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\RASA\\data\\examples\\RasaFormat.json",
    "cors_origins": ["*"],
    "aws_endpoint_url": null,
    "token": null,
    "num_threads": 2,
    "port": 5000
}
```

Here is my LUIS model

```
{
  "luis_schema_version": "2.1.0",
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "phraseListDemo",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "None"
    },
    {
      "name": "PersonalInfo"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "city"
    },
    {
      "name": "Contact"
    },
    {
      "name": "Email"
    },
    {
      "name": "FirstName"
    },
    {
      "name": "LastName"
    }
  ],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [],
  "bing_entities": [
    "datetimeV2"
  ],
  "actions": [],
  "model_features": [
    {
      "name": "city",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "jaipur,bangalore,florida,japan,delhi,pune,bombay,mumbai,chennai,hyderabad,kolkata,chandigarh,ahmedabad,china,lucknow,germany,noida,indore,nagpur,coimbatore,bhopal,banglore,india,patna,maharashtra,surat,kanpur,guwahati,ludhiana,gwalior,aurangabad,amritsar,rajkot,gujarat,madurai,pradesh,dehradun,raipur,ranchi,varanasi,jabalpur,jodhpur,srinagar,mangalore,udaipur,jamshedpur,vadodara",
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "name": "contact",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "8947847422,8967564556,8967907890,1235712345,8989898989,1231231231",
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Email",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "xyz@email.com, abc@gmail.com",
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "name": "emailid",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "xyz@email.com, abc@gmail.com",
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "name": "FirstName",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "amit,ankur,ankit,ram,shyam,kunal,saikat,sundar,krishna,vikram,mohan,vijay,karthik,sunil,vivek,gopal,John,Chris,satish,surya,ajay,raju,suresh,sanjay,rajesh,ravi,ramesh,arun,rakesh,manoj,anil,kiran,sachin,dinesh,pradeep,raj,ashok,priya,prakash,david,mukesh,praveen,mahesh,naresh,anand,kumar,nikhil,michael,paul,naveen,nitin,srinivas,prasad,vinod,kishore,james,vinay,thomas",
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "name": "LastName",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "Gupta,Sharma,Jain,kumar,singh,mishra,Mukherjee,goswami,verma,yadav,patel,ghosh,das",
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "name": "MID",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "M1039205,M1039222,M1036767,M1048967,M1056789,M1028967,M1088967",
      "activated": true
    }
  ],
  "regex_features": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "my name is ankur",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "FirstName",
          "startPos": 11,
          "endPos": 15
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "my contact number is 1231234123",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Contact",
          "startPos": 21,
          "endPos": 30
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "my firstname is amit and lastname is gupta",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "FirstName",
          "startPos": 16,
          "endPos": 19
        },
        {
          "entity": "LastName",
          "startPos": 37,
          "endPos": 41
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "my email is a@gmail.com",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Email",
          "startPos": 12,
          "endPos": 22
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "kunal is one person",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "FirstName",
          "startPos": 0,
          "endPos": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "myself singh and my dob comes on 24 may",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "LastName",
          "startPos": 7,
          "endPos": 11
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "my name is gupta and my dob is in month april",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "LastName",
          "startPos": 11,
          "endPos": 15
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "my name is amit and my date of birth is in month of march",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "FirstName",
          "startPos": 11,
          "endPos": 14
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone point where I am going wrong?

**Update**
Here is my RASA format training data

```
{
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "entity_synonyms": [
      {
        "value": "city",
        "synonyms": [
          "jaipur",
          "bangalore",
          "florida",
          "japan",
          "delhi",
          "pune",
          "bombay",
          "mumbai",
          "chennai",
          "hyderabad",
          "kolkata",
          "chandigarh",
          "ahmedabad",
          "china",
          "lucknow",
          "germany",
          "noida",
          "indore",
          "nagpur",
          "coimbatore",
          "bhopal",
          "banglore",
          "india",
          "patna",
          "maharashtra",
          "surat",
          "kanpur",
          "guwahati",
          "ludhiana",
          "gwalior",
          "aurangabad",
          "amritsar",
          "rajkot",
          "gujarat",
          "madurai",
          "pradesh",
          "dehradun",
          "raipur",
          "ranchi",
          "varanasi",
          "jabalpur",
          "jodhpur",
          "srinagar",
          "mangalore",
          "udaipur",
          "jamshedpur",
          "vadodara"
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "contact",
        "synonyms": [
          "8947847422",
          "8967564556",
          "8967907890",
          "1235712345",
          "8989898989",
          "1231231231"
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "Email",
        "synonyms": [
          "xyz@email.com",
          " abc@gmail.com"
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "emailid",
        "synonyms": [
          "xyz@email.com",
          " abc@gmail.com"
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "FirstName",
        "synonyms": [
          "amit",
          "ankur",
          "ankit",
          "ram",
          "shyam",
          "kunal",
          "saikat",
          "sundar",
          "krishna",
          "vikram",
          "mohan",
          "vijay",
          "karthik",
          "sunil",
          "vivek",
          "gopal",
          "John",
          "Chris",
          "satish",
          "surya",
          "ajay",
          "raju",
          "suresh",
          "sanjay",
          "rajesh",
          "ravi",
          "ramesh",
          "arun",
          "rakesh",
          "manoj",
          "anil",
          "kiran",
          "sachin",
          "dinesh",
          "pradeep",
          "raj",
          "ashok",
          "priya",
          "prakash",
          "david",
          "mukesh",
          "praveen",
          "mahesh",
          "naresh",
          "anand",
          "kumar",
          "nikhil",
          "michael",
          "paul",
          "naveen",
          "nitin",
          "srinivas",
          "prasad",
          "vinod",
          "kishore",
          "james",
          "vinay",
          "thomas"
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "LastName",
        "synonyms": [
          "Gupta",
          "Sharma",
          "Jain",
          "kumar",
          "singh",
          "mishra",
          "Mukherjee",
          "goswami",
          "verma",
          "yadav",
          "patel",
          "ghosh",
          "das"
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "MID",
        "synonyms": [
          "M1039205",
          "M1039222",
          "M1036767",
          "M1048967",
          "M1056789",
          "M1028967",
          "M1088967"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "regex_features": [],
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "text": "my name is ankur",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "FirstName",
            "value": "ankur",
            "start": 11,
            "end": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "my contact number is 1231234123",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "Contact",
            "value": "1231234123",
            "start": 21,
            "end": 30
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "my firstname is amit and lastname is gupta",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "FirstName",
            "value": "amit",
            "start": 16,
            "end": 19
          },
          {
            "entity": "LastName",
            "value": "gupta",
            "start": 37,
            "end": 41
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "my email is a@gmail.com",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "Email",
            "value": "a@gmail.com",
            "start": 12,
            "end": 22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "kunal is one person",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "FirstName",
            "value": "kunal",
            "start": 0,
            "end": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "myself singh and my dob comes on 24 may",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "LastName",
            "value": "singh",
            "start": 7,
            "end": 11
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "my name is gupta and my dob is in month april",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "LastName",
            "value": "gupta",
            "start": 11,
            "end": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "my name is amit and my date of birth is in month of march",
        "intent": "PersonalInfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "FirstName",
            "value": "amit",
            "start": 11,
            "end": 14
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the warning message points out, the `start` and the `end` have probably being incorrectly set causing some white-spaces to be included at the token boundaries (either start or the end). 
For example, a sentence like this (from your luis model)

 `{
      "text": "kunal is one person",
      "intent": "PersonalInfo",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "FirstName",
          "startPos": 0,
          "endPos": 4
        }
      ]
    },`

might(incorrectly)  have the `start` to be `1` and `end` to be `5` in the training data.

Maybe try using the [Rasa NLU Trainer](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-nlu-trainer) to visualize the training data and see is that's the case?

This had happened to me too. Correcting the `start` and `end` numbers fixed it.

Comment: why does the `start` and `end` position start at 1 and not 0? If I simply increment the indices, won't it throw `Array Out Of Bounds` exception?

Comment: For this utterance **show me chinese restaurants** The index for entity `chinese` with start position 8 and end position as 15. Check this [link](http://nlu.rasa.ai/dataformat.html)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Like, I said starting the the `start` at `1` would be INCORRECT and this _might_ be throwing the error.

I haven't looked at your training data, so I can't comment _what exactly_ the error is. 

But from the error message I can say that the `start` and `end` indices are misaligned in some training examples; causing some white-space to be included at the start or the end of the token.  

Did you try using the Rasa NLU trainer visualizer to see if that's the case?

Comment: If you can share the training data file, I can probably figure the error

Comment: I have updated my question and included the RASA format Training data and included all the synonyms in the synonyms_value object.

Comment: Umm, I can't find any of the sentences like `what is my name?` in the training data. Are you sure you ran the script on this training data? 

On a tangential note, you might wanna go through the documentation of synonyms in rasa, I'm not sure you're using them correctly

Comment: I resolved the issue, it seems I was not annotating the utterances correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. Also, as I mentioned, try and read the docs of synonyms in rasa. I'm not sure if you're using them as intended

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Hi, i am getting the same error. Can you tell me how did you resolve this issue?