# Entity annotation has whitespaces in RASA NLU

Tags: c#, nlp, rasa-nlu

I was going through the [Training Data RASA Format](http://nlu.rasa.ai/dataformat.html#common-examples) as detailed here.

```
{
  "text": "show me chinese restaurants",
  "intent": "restaurant_search",
  "entities": [
    {
      "start": 8,
      "end": 15,
      "value": "chinese",
      "entity": "cuisine"
    }
  ]
}
```

The substring `Chinese` is marked as an entity from the 8th to 15th index of the utterance.

I have written a small C# program to verify the correctness of the index of the characters in the utterance.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "show me chinese restaurants";
            int i = 0;

            foreach(var item in s.ToCharArray())
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item, i++);
        }
    }
```

But when I run the program I get the following output:

```
s - 0
h - 1
o - 2
w - 3
  - 4
m - 5
e - 6
  - 7
c - 8
h - 9
i - 10
n - 11
e - 12
s - 13
e - 14
  - 15
r - 16
e - 17
s - 18
t - 19
a - 20
u - 21
r - 22
a - 23
n - 24
t - 25
s - 26
```

Notice the bizarre behavior of the annotation of text the substring `Chinese` starts at index 8 and ends at 15 with a whitespace.

But the substring `Chinese` should start at index 8 and end at position 14.

When I train the same text `Chinese` with indices starting at position 8 and ending at 14. I get `Misaligned Entity Annotation` warning by RASA as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753239/how-to-resolve-misaligned-entity-annotation-error-in-rasa-nlu).

Can someone explain this strange behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the link [provided](http://nlu.rasa.ai/dataformat.html#common-examples) I may have come up with a possible explanation:

> which together make a python style range to apply to the string, e.g. in the example below, with text="show me chinese restaurants", then text[8:15] == 'chinese'

This lead me down a path that I was thinking

> Hmmm that is weird i wonder if python does indexing wierdly

I spun up a quick app to prove this:

```
text = "show me chinese restaurants"
print(text[8:15])
```

Now this may not make sense because the character in space 15 of the array here is in all fact a space. Which led me onto thi article:

> https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

It seems that the operator they are using in the example here `text[8:15]` slices the array, they use the example:

`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

`a[1:4]` which outputs: `[2, 3, 4]`

and explains it as such

> Let me explain it. The 1 means to start at second element in the list (note that the slicing index starts at 0). The 4 means to end at the fifth element in the list, but not include it. The colon in the middle is how Python's lists recognize that we want to use slicing to get objects in the list.

So it seems that the second parameter of the slicing is exclusive.

Hope this helps

p.s. Had to learn and setup some python stuff :D